# React-native android module builds old code

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I'm pretty new in react native , so i'm building simple native module from facebook examples https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

everything is working fine until I want to change smth in java code, it always remains the same old one. JS in index.android.js changes like a charm but java code simply remains old one. 
There was a topic on github but there solutions to clear the cache did not work for me nor this `rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*` nor `react-native run-android  --reset-cache`

Any ideas? Thanks for any advices i simply cant work like that!

Comment: For changes in native (e.g. Java) code you have to rebuild the project. A simple refresh won't do. Are you building the project again each time you change native code?

Comment: @Andru Yes! Well i think so. I call 'react-native run-android' from console, but nothing changes, should I run some other command?

Comment: I found the solution for now  - kill terminal with all processes helps in 90% .